# How can I monitor the winforms TextBox.SelectionStart property for changes?

Tags: .net, winforms, textbox

I have a multiline text box, and I'd like to display the user's current line number and column number in a label below the text box. It looks like I can get the line number and column number using the SelectionStart property, GetLineFromCharIndex method, and GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine method. However, I can't see any event that gets fired every time the selection changes in the text box.

The best I can see is to monitor the KeyPress and MouseDown events and check the SelectionStart property after each event. I suppose I could use a timer to watch for changes, but that feels weird.

Have I missed something?

Comment: Just check SelectionLength in both MouseUp and KeyUp events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be robust, you're probably going to have to add a timer, and just check it regularly; [from here](http://bytes.com/groups/net-c/239322-textbox-selectionchanged-equivalent), the control doesn't post suitable win32 messages (EN_SELCHANGE) to do this as an event.

Answer (score 0):

To get SelectionChanged events, you can also convert your TextBox to a RichTextBox. RichTextBoxes behave a little differently than TextBoxes so this may not be an ideal solution, but at least there is a [SelectionChanged event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionchanged.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I particularly want the simplicity of a text box. I'm willing to take the inelegance of watching with a timer in exchange.